# Реализация поддержки библиотекой подключений к разным БД

Tags: java, база-данных, jdbc

Имеется библиотека, которая используя JDBC подключается к БД по указанной строкe подключения.
На данный момент поддерживается только MS SQL, но необходимо добавить поддержку и других баз данных. В идеале библиотека должна работать с любыми БД, для которых имеется JDBC драйвер. Проблема в том, что я не могу протестировать/установить все возможные БД. Конечно сразу приходит на ум ORM, но библиотека нужна именно для работы с java.sql.* классами, а также имеется запрет на ORM со стороны руководства.

Насколько я понимаю, то для добавления поддержки работы с разными БД мне необходимо:

- определять тип необходимого драйвера по строке подключения и регистрировать;
- иметь в списке зависимостей библиотеки (pom.xml) все поддерживаемые JDBC драйвера для регистрации;

Так ли это реализуется или имеется более правильный способ? Нужна ли в принципе регистрация драйвера?

Фрагмент pom.xml:

```xml
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
  <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>${mssql-jdbc}</version>
  <!--
       Будет ли возникать ошибка
       при недоступности одного или
       нескольких драйверов в runtime?
       С runtime scope компиляция не выполняется.
  -->
  <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc11 -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
  <artifactId>ojdbc11</artifactId>
  <version>${ojdbc}</version>
  <!--
       Будет ли возникать ошибка
       при недоступности одного или
       нескольких драйверов в runtime?
       С runtime scope компиляция не выполняется.
  -->
  <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
</dependency>
```

Пример регистрации драйвера:

```java
import com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver;

public class SqlExportService
{
  private ServiceSettings settings;

  public SqlExportService(ServiceSettings settings)
  {
    this.settings = settings;
    registerDrivers( settings.getConnectionString() );
  }

  private boolean registerDrivers( String connectionString )
  {
    try
    {
      if( connectionString.startsWith("jdbc:oracle:") )
      {
        DriverManager.registerDriver( new OracleDriver() );
      }
      else if( connectionString.startsWith("jdbc:sqlserver:") )
      {
        DriverManager.registerDriver( new SQLServerDriver() );
      }
    }
    catch ( SQLException e )
    {
      logger.error( "An error occurred while registering the driver in the manager.", e );
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  public ResultSet executeStatement( String sqlStatement )
  {
    ResultSet result = null;
    try (Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection( this.settings.connectionString );
         Statement statement = connection.createStatement())
    {
      result = statement.executeQuery( sqlStatement );
    }
    catch ( SQLException e )
    {
      logger.error("An error occurred while executing the SQL query: \"" + sqlStatement + "\"", e);
    }
    return result;
  }
}
```

---

#### Ссылки по теме

- [First Steps in JDBC](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/F49540_01/DOC/java.815/a64685/basic1.htm)

Comment: на самом деле вам нужна орм, иначе вы очень скоро наткнетесь на огромное количество проблем. например, Hibernate

Comment: @Дмитрий не могу использовать ORM. Дополнил вопрос уточняющей информацией.

Comment: мне кажется вы не правильно оцениваете проблему. для вас проблема в том, что вы не можете установить все бд. если это прямо принципиально, то, как вариант, докер в помощь. а вот что вы будете делать с диалектами sql? это вопрос

Comment: [DataSource](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/sqldatasources.html), не?

Comment: @Дмитрий диалекты уже не моя проблема. Мне нужно реализовать библиотеку, которая может подключаться к различным БД по строке подключения.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov правильно ли я понимаю, что DataSource должен настраиваться на исполняемой машине? Если "да", то это категорически не подходит.

Comment: если вы не хотите, чтобы датасорс настраивался на клиентской машине, то и ваш способ не подходит. вот это DriverManager.registerDriver( new SQLServerDriver() ); не скомпилируется потому как никто не будет добавлять драйвера всех без данных в зависимости. как вариант использовать Class.forName(...);, где подставлять дрова типа oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver. список этих классов (поддерживаемые базы данных), выносить в проперти. тогда при старте можно пройтись по ним итератором и понять, какой драйвер сейчас подключен, потому как он найдется в зависимостях. а от этого уже плясать

Comment: ну или заставлять указать это в пропертях того, кто будет это юзать, это все упростит. тут уже зависит от задачи...

Comment: @Дмитрий "да" - идеальный вариант, когда из всех поддерживаемых драйверов вызывающий код имеет в своих зависимостях один - который используется. Если я правильно понял, то Вы предлагаете так: var driver = (oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver").getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance(); java.sql.DriverManager.registerDriver( driver ); В этом случае в Maven зависимости можно оставить provided, или?

Comment: нет, вы снова таки кастуете к конкретному классу, это снова не скомпилится. набейте в гугле Class.forName jdbc и посмотрите, как создается датасорс просто по стрингу, который является полным именем класса драйвера бд

Comment: @Дмитрий я тоже об этом подумал (приведение к типу). Сейчас SonarLint ругнулся [предупреждением S4925](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-4925) при вызове `Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")`. Цитата "when using JDBC 4.0 drivers, this is no longer required and Class.forName() can be safely removed because JDBC 4.0 (JDK 6) drivers available in the classpath are automatically loaded.", т.е. мне вообше не нужно заморачиваться и можно получить соединение просто обратившись к DriverManager передав ему строку подключения?

Comment: Во-первых,  не  использовать ORM.  Во-вторых,  ненвдо  в  классе  прописсывать  все  возможные классы драйверов.  Можно сделать проще. DriverManager.registerDriver( "Load_Driver_Name_from_properties_file" ); .  Также из пропертей брать формирование  строк.  И свамое  главное  посмотреть  спецификацию  jdbc 4.1.  По моему там эта проблема решелась... Ой уже  кто-то  написал подобное.

Comment: @XelaNimed я такие вещи делал лет 10 назад, когда деревья были большими)) тогда делали так, сейчас делают иначе: Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(serverURI); это написано в любой спецификации. пробуйте, не думаю, что это сложно, тем более вы уже понимаете в какую сторону бежать